# how to create a trigger for Shift + A key press in oracle forms 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

In oracle form builder, I want to use a trigger for Shift + A, (it just cant be any other key, dont ask me why please), but there are only a few specific KEY- triggers available. I just want to run some PL/SQL code whenever Shift + A is pressed in a form.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here;

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4488542/how-to-create-a-trigger-for-shift-a-key-press-in-oracle-forms-12c

The Oracle Forms Forum is a great place to get answers to all your Oracle Forms question.  It's also a great place to share your ideas for future versions.  Check it out:

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/forms